# What is the difference between react usecontext and global variables

Tags: reactjs

The function of react context is to facilitate the component to pass values, but it is not responsive. It needs to cooperate with usestate to achieve responsiveness. What's the difference between using global variables and setting a layer of usestate can also achieve the effect of component transparent transmission. I can think of the difference between context and global variables is that context only transmits data to wrapped components, while global variables have no such restriction

Comment: Updating context in one component should update/rerender another component that uses the context. Do global variables have this property? That when you change them other components that use them are updated as well? I don't think so :)

Comment: After using context, it is actually context Provider value = XXX. The XXX data is required to be responsive. The component update in XXX will be triggered only when XXX changes. In fact, after using the context, XXX must be defined in conjunction with usestate to trigger the update. If the context does not cooperate with usestate, it is actually similar to the global variable

Answer (score 5):

`props` and `context` are the ways that react has for moving data between components. Built into these are the fact that if you rerender the source component and it has a new value for the prop/context, then the destination component will rerender too. The child component does not need to somehow register an event listener on the props/context, and then set state when the value changes; it's enough that the props/context changed.

If you do a global variable, then yes, it can in principle be available to all components. However, you will need to write code which listens to changes in that global variable (for example, with an event emitter or an observable), and then every component that consumes it will need to set local state when the global value changes, in order to rerender itself.

> context only transmits data to wrapped components, while global variables have no such restriction

While you describe this as a restriction, it's sometimes a very useful benefit. For example, suppose you have a Theme object that sets the colors for your app. It's provided via context, and your ui components use it to style themselves.

But you also want to let the user change the theme, and see a preview of the change. Since the Theme is using context, you can create a new context provider that just wraps around the preview part of your app. Components inside the preview will use the modified theme, while the rest of the app behaves as normal.

Comment: Both context and global variables have functions similar to data transmission, but obviously, if context and global variables are not used, the global variables must be responsive, and the main response of react is usestate. The usestate hook must be defined in the function. It is difficult for global variables to use these built-in hooks unless they are response variables such as mobx. In addition, if global variables are not flexible in context and want to modify variables in one place without affecting variables in other places, it seems impossible to use global variables

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I probably know what you mean. I'm a Chinese and most of my English is translated. If the expression is not standard, please forgive me, hahaha

Comment: sorry,I still can't understand your context theme case. Can you provide a general code to reflect the difference between context and global variables